# command line parameters separated by null character

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, realpath, ifs

As filenames may contain spaces and new lines `\n`, I am using null character as field separator. But I do not know how to say to `find` that the input directories are null character separated.

My failed attempt:

```
foo()
{
  IFS='\0'
  find "$@"
}

$ mkdir 'oneword' 'two words'
$ IFS='\0' foo $(realpath -z 'oneword' 'two words')
```

**How to tell `find` that the input directories are separated by zeros?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use xargs:

```
realpath -z 'oneword' 'two words' | xargs -0 find
```

Or:

```
foo() {
  local A=() I=0 IFS=''
  while read -rd $'\0' A[I++]; do :; done 
  find "${A[@]}"
}
realpath -z 'oneword' 'two words' | foo  ## Under subshell or pipe
foo < <(realpath -z 'oneword' 'two words')  ## No subshell
```

You can use another fd if needed:

```
foo() {
  local A=() I=0 IFS=''
  while read -rd $'\0' -u 4 A[I++]; do :; done 
  find "${A[@]}"
}
foo 4< <(realpath -z 'oneword' 'two words')
```

Note: Using IFS to split your variable's values to multiple arguments can cause pathname expansion and is not commendable. It requires modification of IFS as well which could affect other functions.